# why not using padding as display as they show?

Tags: html, css

I am newbie with html css and here is my problem.

I want to code a page as this page https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_band.htm#band
I want to see the button's information, and here is what I got
[image: button's information]

As you can see in this picture, I see the button contact's padding is 12px 24px.
But when I code this button, when I set the padding like this

```
#nav li a {
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 46px;
padding:  12px 24px;
}
```

The button became like this picture [image: button when set padding become 12px 24px]

They said to me that I must set the padding like this

```
#nav li a {
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 46px;
padding:  0px 24px;
}
```

And here is what I got

[image: button when set padding become 0px 24px]

Maybe it is ok when set padding 0px 24px.

I am very confusing because why I must set padding different with the padding it show in the page ?

Could you please explain this problem for me ?
Thank you very much for your time.